# Constantly Getting Slice Indexing Error With Pandas excel_read in Jupyter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing, jupyter-notebook

Here is my *insanely* simple script I'm trying to run in Jupyter Notebook. I'm completely new to this but seem to be able to access the right directory and see the correct file. help.xlsx is just a simple excel file with a few strings as the first row and corresponding rows of numbers underneath. It's meant as a test file because literally nothing else works either. I've tried with csv read using csv files and files available online. They can read it but I keep getting the same error (I'll put it below)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

def io_hw(out_path):
    df = pd.read_excel('./help.xlsx')
    head_df = df.head(df)
    head_df.to_csv('./tester.csv')
    return df, head_df
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [   hello  this   is  awful
E       0      1     4    7      6
E       1      2     3    5      8
E       2     12    11    9     10] of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

/Users/Shea/miniconda3/envs/em212/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3066: TypeError
```

No matter what I do, no matter what file I use, it's the *exact* same error each time (just with different invalid indexes) and I have tried googling, looking it up on here, nothing seems to solve the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this statement: `df.head(df)`

In the pandas's `.head()` module you have to feed in the number of rows, and not specify the dataframe twice. If you want the fist 3 rows for instance, you can say `df.head(n=3)`.

If you want all the rows don't bother with the `.head()` module, and directly save the excel DF to CSV, like such: `df.to_csv('./tester.csv')`

The official documentation of this is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)